# Recursion of arbitrary complexity replicated with iteration?

Tags: python, loops, recursion

Recursion can be an elegant approach to problem solving. Some mathematical functions are defined recursively. However, Python's Benevolent Dictator For Life, Guido van Rossum, as a matter of strategy, has [decided not to provide for tail recursion elimination](http://neopythonic.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html). Tail recursion elimination would make tracing the path of code back from deep in recursive function calls up to the main process level impossible.

What this means is that functions that call themselves, typically with new arguments, are limited in the number of times that they can do this. The limit is typically arbitrarily large for small recursion problems, but arbitrarily small for actions that could be processed as long lists, and is usually set to 1000 by default.

The trivial case, is illustrated here:

```
def foo(): 
    foo()
```

and with:

```
>>> foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in foo
```

[... [1000 (default limit on recursion for Python)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) identical lines, each representing a frame of execution.]

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in foo
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The problem with setting the recursion limit higher is that it may work for incrementally larger problems, but eventually you'll run out of memory for all of the frames, causing your process to crash.

Complexity specific to recursion has two dimensions: differing arguments and differing functions.
So here's some recursive code of arbitrary complexity, a minimal reproducible example, three functions that select themselves pseudorandomly and pass in two arguments, the last argument will vary based on the calling function:

```
import random

MAX = 10000

def foo(my_list, item):
    my_list.append(item)
    if len(my_list) < MAX:
        return random.choice(FUNCS)(my_list, 'foo')
    else:
        return my_list

def bar(my_list, item):
    my_list.append(item[::-1]) # reverse the string, for variety.
    return random.choice(FUNCS)(my_list, 'bar')

def baz(my_list, item):
    my_list.append(item)
    return random.choice(FUNCS)(my_list, 'baz')

FUNCS = (foo, bar, baz)

# And now call `foo`:

''.join(foo([], 'init!'))[:50]
```

and we get our traceback:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in baz
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 275, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

But for lower recursion depths this works.

```
MAX = 900
''.join(foo([], 'init!'))[:50]
```

returns:

```
'init!foobazoofrabbaroofbarfoooofrabrabbaroofrabrab'
```

Beginners new to Python will run into this problem, and I have recently been asked about it more frequently, as they don't know what to do to solve the problem. So the question is, **can recursion of arbitrary complexity be substituted by iteration in Python?** And is there a model for transforming recursive code into iterative code?

Comment: You may be interested in this [blog series](http://blog.moertel.com/tags/recursion.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is: Yes, all recursion of any level of complexity can be rewritten in iterative form.**

The general model is that we can replace this arbitrarily complex recursive behavior by removing the recursive call in each function and moving the condition and logic outside the function in a while loop, and ensuring the new arguments get passed into each new call of the function. I will provide examples here.

**Trivial Case**

For the trivial case, `def foo(): foo()` that means we would alter the code as follows:

```
def foo():
    pass

while True:
    # we have no variables to pass or assign
    foo()
```

And we now have a loop with unlimited iteration instead of Python's limited recursion.

**Complex Case**

For the more complex case, we do the same, but the while loop contains our conditional exit from the `foo` function. The argument that changes is `item` and it is still set by the function randomly called. We wrap our while loop in a function so that we can call it like we did with `foo`

```
import random

MAX = 10000

def foo(my_list, item):
    my_list.append(item)
    return 'foo'

def bar(my_list, item):
    my_list.append(item[::-1])
    return 'bar'

def baz(my_list, item):
    my_list.append(item)
    return 'baz'

FUNCS = (foo, bar, baz)

def init(my_list, item='init!'):
    #     same condition   ---  item != 'foo' since we'd only stop recursing there.
    while len(my_list) < MAX or item != 'foo': 
        # Note `item` is both passed to and set by the function
        item = random.choice(FUNCS)(my_list, item)
    return my_list

''.join(init([], 'init!'))[:50]
```

without lessening our MAX value, returns:

```
'init!zabrabbarbazzabbarbazbazzabbarfoozabbarbazbaz'
```

This is less elegant in that we need to add control flow outside the actions that need repeating, and we can't simply dive into the recursive function. However, our stacktrace is far shorter. If we have an error, we are likely to have a far less difficult time pinpointing the source of it.

**Conclusion**

Whether the change is more or less readable and maintainable is debatable. Nevertheless, for large looping tasks, in Python, building your code using an iterative model is the only way to do it.